# Check if strings in an array contain a punctuation or numeric substring?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, ios8, substring, nsrange

My method currently checks if a substring exists within an array, but I was wondering if there's a way for it to also work with punctuation and numbers. Say I have an array of:

```
@[@"apple", @"!!", @"apps!", @"banana"];
```

and my substring is `@"!"`, I want it to spit out: `@"!!"`, and `@"apps!"`

Or another example:

```
@[@"apple", @"6:30", @"6 Pizzas", @"26"];
```

and my substring is `@"6"`, I want it to spit out: `@"6:30"`, and `@"6"`, and `@"6 Pizzas"`

Is there a way of doing this using `NSRange substringRange = [wordsArray rangeOfString:currentWord];`

At the moment punctuation characters aren't being recognized. :/

Comment: what have you tried? Did you checked the regexes? I dont know if you can feed regex into the rangeOfString but you could iterate over list and test with simple regex `/\W/g` for any non-word character or basically use what you want to match `/6/g`

Comment: So right now I have an if, else if, else if statement where I organize my output (exact words first, then words where the substring comes at the beginning, and lastly if the substring exists at all). This is for alphabetic characters and numbers. I was thinking of adding another else if where if the substring matches a string in a punctuations character set, to add it to my array of suggestions, but I'm not sure if that's the best way to do it.

Comment: Hah! Actually I figured it out, so what I was doing was passing the current word using an ```enumerateSubstringsInRange``` block, where I was using ```NSStringEnumerationByWords``` which would automatically ignore non-alphanumeric values.

Answer (score 0):

Using `NSPredicates` makes this work much easier.

```
NSArray *stringArray = @[@"apple", @"!!", @"apps!", @"banana"];

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate PredicateWithFormat:@"SELF CONTAINS[cd] '%@'",searchChar];
NSArray *resultArray = [stringArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```